# Force Finnix (Linux Rescue Disk) to shutdown without prompting to remove CD when pressing power button

Tags: linux, scripting, power-management

When shutting down Finnix Rescue Disk (using power button), I got the following message:

> Please remove the live-medium, close the tray (if any) and press ENTER
> to continue:

Well, if I don't use power button, I can just trigger `poweroff -f` , where the -f option to force the rescue disk to shutdown, this will shutdown the OS without the above interactive message.

But using the power button it will not shutdown the OS with option -f. So how do you skip this message when shutting down the Finnix Rescue Disk using power button?

I found this post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/528577/how-to-skip-please-remove-the-installation-medium-then-press-enter) which talks about

1. modifying the script for /run/casper-no-prompt (but it doesn't work probably because this file is only for Ubuntu-based)
2. putting `noprompt` and I even put `noeject` at the boot parameter but it has no effect

Note that I'm able to edit this ISO file and repack it back and make it bootable. So, is there a file that I can modify to skip the above interactive message when shutting down Finnix like putting a boot script that will trigger after pressing power button. I found that post here about [Graceful shutdown via power button](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159316/graceful-shutdown-via-power-button) but it talks about CentOS only but I don't think this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried several methods like using `rc6.d` or `rc0.d` but all of them are not working. Then I found this helpful [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/479048/343508) about how to run a script right before shutdown. My aim is to override the shutdown command that is being triggered to `shutdown -f`

The post asked me to create a script in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown`. When I navigate to this directory, I found a script called `live-tools.shutdown`. The file contains the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/live-medium-eject
```

So, I read the other file `/bin/live-medium-eject` and I found out this is the file has the code to wait for user input (press enter to eject disk). So I just need to comment the code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#/bin/live-medium-eject
```

Then when using the power button, it will not ask for ejecting Disk. Solved.

Another way I can think of without disturbing the code is to create a new script inside `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown` called something like `areboot` (with the first character of `a` so it might execute first) and inside that script I can put this code and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
reboot -f
```

I think this will work but I haven't tested this. The first one works but I'm not sure if the script is needed by others after I disabled it.

Comment: Your first method will work for sure, but just a style point: it's a general principle with `systemd` that if you have something under `[/usr]/lib/systemd/...` that you need to override, you can (and should) do it by placing a file with the exact same name in the corresponding path under `/etc/systemd/...`. In this case, you could run `mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system-shutdown; ln -s /dev/null /etc/systemd/system-shutdown/live-tools.shutdown` to override the existing script in a "standard" way.

Comment: @telcoM thanks for the tips!